# How To Secure My Api Used For Customer Login Without Making It Vulnerable To Others

Tags: php, json, angularjs, security, authentication

I am very new to development with angularjs.
I am creating a user login system using angularjs. 
I created a user login system using angularjs using json data.
But using my api link in controllers is vulnerable to anyone who is inside the source code to my login page.

I want to secure my api to be unvulnerable to anyone. Using the source code can help anyone to see all the users to my platform. Also if I am hashing the password then also some techy might decode the password.

Please help me with angular or json to secure my login platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a hash password, you can add salt value into that password then after you can create a secured hash password.

You can use [`bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt):

```
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(+20);
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(userId, salt);
return hash;
```

Another user can decode this password but they can not create the same.

Comment: Sorry for inturrupt, but I am very new for all the concepts here.
I would like to be more clear about salt.

We use decoding only to get the true value right?
If a person is decoding the password then the decoded value must be the exact block which a person is trying to decode, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
bcrypt is not an encryption function, it's a password hashing function. Hashing is mathematical one-way functions, meaning there is no* way to reverse the output string to get the input string.

*of course only Siths deal in absolutes and there are a few attacks against hashes. But none of them are "reversing" the hashing.

create a password:

const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(+20);
const generatedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(data, salt);

we can compare a hash password 
data=Test@123
hash=******
ex:const comparePassword = bcrypt.compareSync(data, hash);
You will get your password is matched or not
```